# How do I send an HTTPS POST Request with XML Data in Java

Tags: java, android, httpclient, http-post

I am new to android and building an application to send an HTTPS POST request with XML data (mainly Login & Password) to a web service. I tried, I was only successful in getting back a response with ONLY the Login Page, not sure why the login credentials were not validated on the server side.

Is there any way I can print out the data written to the https connection, so I am sure the
email info and password has been sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I did similar thing. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip96.html?page=1) and it worked fine. In your case you just have to pass XML data as the POST parameter.

Also remember to include all hidden values in your POST request. This can be the reason why your login in unsucessful.

Answer (score 0):

You should activate Logging of the apache commons http client to see what's going on, add this lines to the `onCreate()` Method of your main activity:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").
     setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);        
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").
     setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

after this call the following on the command line:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE
```

You will have a quite detailed output of what is send to the server and what comes back from it in the logcat (either in eclipse or just with `adb logcat`)